# Settings for "User Consent" in Azure AD B2C do not load

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

i am currently trying to implement a "System-of-Systems" authentication architecture in Azure AD B2C.The user of an application should actively agree to allow access to his sensitive data.

For the setting of the "User Consents" I am currently trying to access the "Enterprise Apps" of Azure AD. I get an error when loading the setting.

[The loading error as a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQxph.png)

Do you have an idea why it does not load?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The backend request will show this error while trying to access **Consent and permissions | User consent settings (Preview)** blade:

```
GET https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/MsGraph/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=hasPermissionClassifications%20eq%20true&$expand=delegatedPermissionClassifications HTTP/1.1

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "$expand of back links is not supported for mega tenants.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "18567d14-93e9-4787-8dcf-c3d82c1166b5",
      "date": "2020-06-03T09:28:26"
    }
  }
}
```

We can see that the request includes `$expand`, which should be the reason of the loading error of this page. A Mega-Tenant will typically refer to B2C/MSA tenants in the scope of Azure.

So it should be a temporary problem with the Azure B2C portal currently. You can raise a ticket for more information about a suitable fix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  The problem still exists. I want to provide a B2C access panel for normal users. Are there any walkarounds? And where can I create the ticket?

Comment: @fasol No. As far as I know, there is no workaround. Unless you enable Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf to Yes. Raising support ticket is a paid service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: @fasol As far as I know, currently admin account can only do the consent in B2C Portal by click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" in the Azure AD app. It's not supported to implement the admin consent workflow in B2C.